# How to avoid user access to .xhtml page in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF and writing first simply jsf web app.

URL with .jsf are mapping to .xhtml files in WebContent but why I can open .xhtml in web browser with all jsf tags. How to protect this?

Comment: Try to put them under WEB-INF

Comment: @ahvargas: This doesn't work for JSF.

Comment: Are restrictions additive? For example: <security-constraint> <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name> <web-resource-collection> <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name> <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> </web-resource-collection> <auth-constraint /> </security-constraint> <security-constraint> <web-resource-collection> <web-resource-name>Auth</web-resource-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </web-resource-collection> <auth-constraint> <role-name>Admin</role-name> </auth-constraint> </security-constraint> does not restrict raw xhtml-files to be transmitted to Users with

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could add a security constraint to your `web.xml` blocking all requests to `*.xhtml`.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 11):

Apart from defining a `<security-constraint>` to block direct access to `.xhtml` files as correctly answered by Stacker on this question, you could also just change the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` mapping from `*.jsf` to `*.xhtml`.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In JSF 1.x this used to end up in an infinite loop, but in JSF 2.x not anymore. So you could just call/link all pages as `.xhtml` without fiddling with different extensions. The only disadvantage is that you won't be able to display a "plain" XHTML file without invoking the `FacesServlet`, but such a page should be named `.html` anyway :)

Comment: @s_t_e_v_e: GAE is an odd beast anyway.

Comment: I do not uderstand, if you define <security-constraint> on *.xhtml and <url-pattern> set to *.xhtml then how to set xhtml <welcome-file> that it would not be blocked?

Comment: @michal777: "Apart from ...", so you shouldn't need to define *both*.

Answer (score 2):

On GAE you need two things:

1. edit web.xml as described above
2. add in appengine-web.xml

```
<static-files>
    <exclude path="/**.xhtml" />
</static-files>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a servlet filter

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "XhtmlFilter", urlPatterns = { "*.xhtml" })
public class XhtmlFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(404);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i experienced it, the answer of mk761203 is definitely helpful when setting up a project for google app engine and server faces. without the exclusion of this files, the GAE automatically interpets the files with the .xhtml extension as static files which get served by dedicated servers from googles server farm. read more here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files