# Spring security - restrict xhtml files

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I use *.jsf file types and any given address that ends with .xhtml is not parsed and it shows original code. I want to restrict access to .xhtml files with spring security, however it doesn't work. Spring security works fine for me, so I guess that there's problem with intercept-url:

```
<intercept-url pattern="*.xhtml" access="denyAll" />
```

Is my pattern ok and problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: This can be done in the `web.xml` file directly instead as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5675271/1391249).