# Use custom URL extension with JSF

Tags: jsf, tomcat, servlets

I want to use a custom URL extension for my facelets. Like, let's say, `.asdf` instead of `.xhtml` or `.jsf`.

I added the mapping to my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.asdf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `index.asdf` is located in `WebContent/facelets/common/index.asdf` but if I try to access it with the browser (`http://localhost:8080/Project/facelets/common/index.asdf`)I get the following error message:

> HTTP Status 404 - /Project/facelets/common/index.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /Project/facelets/common/index.jsp
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.39

Note that it says .jsp even though I haven't used the `.jsp` extension anywhere. Any pointers what's wrong there?

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I misunderstood some of the basics here. I renamed my files on disk to index.asdf, which I shouldn't have. They should keep the `.xhtml` extension and only the extension I access them with is the new one. Now everything works as expected. If you want to restrict access to these raw `.xhtml` files use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675913/989919